# How to test async functions that update PublishSubject or BehaviorSubject object (RxDart) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I've been learning flutter for a few weeks and come from an Android background so far I love it and I have also been delighted to find that Flutter was designed with testing in mind from day one. However, I've been having an issue running the following test.

```
main() => {
  test('test get popular repos', () async {
    final testOwner = Owner(1010, "testLink");
    final testRepo =
        Repo(101, testOwner, "testRepo", "description", 'htmlUrl', 500);
    final testRepoResponse = RepoResponse(List.from([testRepo]), null);
    final uiModel = PopRepo(testRepo.owner.avatarUrl, testRepo.name,
        testRepo.description, "Stars: ${testRepo.stargazersCount}");
    final searchData = SearchData(List.from([uiModel]), null);

    final Repository mockRepository = _mockRepository();

    when(mockRepository.getPopularReposForOrg("org"))
        .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(testRepoResponse));

    final repoSearchBloc = RepoSearchPageBloc(mockRepository);
    await repoSearchBloc.getPopularRepos("org");


    await expectLater(repoSearchBloc.resultSubject.stream, emits(searchData));
  }),
};

class _mockRepository extends Mock implements Repository {}
```

My RepoSearchBloc takes data from a Repository and transforms it into the Ui model. Finally it posts that now UI-ready data to the Subject

this is the method under test in the RepoSearchBloc

```
getPopularRepos(String org) async {
if (org == null || org.isEmpty)
  return resultSubject.add(SearchData(List(), null));
RepoResponse response = await _repository.getPopularReposForOrg(org);
if (response.error == null) {
  List<Repo> repoList = response.results;
  repoList.sort((a, b) => a.stargazersCount.compareTo(b.stargazersCount));
  var uiRepoList = repoList
      .map((repo) => PopRepo(repo.owner.avatarUrl, repo.name,
          repo.description, "Stars: ${repo.stargazersCount}"))
      .take(3)
      .toList();
  resultSubject.add(SearchData(uiRepoList, null));
} else {
  ErrorState error = ErrorState(response.error);
  resultSubject.add(SearchData(List(), error));
}
```

When I run the test I keep getting this message no matter what I do it seems with either BehaviorSubject or PublishSubject:

```
ERROR: Expected: should emit an event that <Instance of 'SearchData'>
  Actual: <Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<SearchData>'>
   Which: emitted * Instance of 'SearchData'
```

Any ideas how to get this test to pass?

Comment: What line is throwing the error? What is the stack trace?

Comment: It is the actual test function of the test 
`await expectLater(repoSearchBloc.resultSubject.stream, emits(searchData));`

And the *stack trace* is the block at the end... there is no error really its just not getting the expected result... I dont see why stream is emitting its own own object instead of the subjects payload

Comment: If you were to comment out that `expectLater` and replace it with `print(await repoSearchBloc.resultSubject.stream.first);`, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring this out with the help of a user Nico @Rodsevich of the [Flutter Glitter community](https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter)

anyways using his suggestion to use `await for`

I came up with the following solution which passed

```
    await for (var emittedResult in repoSearchBloc.resultSubject.stream) {
      expect(emittedResult.results[0].repoName, testRepo.name);
      return;
    }
```

The RxDart library has some subject tests [for reference](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/blob/master/test/subject/behavior_subject_test.dart) but my subject being posted to asynchronously did not adhere to their test cases so this solution ended up being just what I needed.

Also @Abion47 's comment also seems to do the job when I move async inside the parameter for expected

```
expectLater( (await repoSearchBloc.resultSubject.stream.first as SearchData).results[0].repoName, testRepo.name);
```